# What is the cardinality of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, where $p$ is a prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was solving past exam papers and stuck on the following problem:

> Let $p$ be a prime number .Suppose $G$ be the group of all $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\Bbb Z_p$,with determinant $1$ under matrix multiplication. Then order of $G$ is which of the following :
>
> 1. $p(p-1)(p+1)$
> 2. $p^2(p-1)$
> 3. $p^3$
> 4. $p^2(p-1)+p$

Can someone explain it? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: The group of $n\times n$ matrices over a field $F$ that have determinant $1$ is known as the *[special linear group of degree $n$ over $F$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group)* and is denoted $\mathrm{SL}_n(F)$ or $\mathrm{SL}(n,F)$. I think this question has already been asked here, though I can't find a duplicate at the moment; in the meantime, the reasoning used in [this analogous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/259973/264) about the general linear group may help you (or, now that you know the name of this group, you could easily look up the answer on Google).

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$  $\not = \mathbb{Z}_p$? The set  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of integers mod $p$ has $p$ elements, whereas the set  $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of $p$-adic integers has many many more!

Answer (score 5):

Can you calculate $|{\rm GL}_2({\bf F}_p)|$? Invertible linear maps correspond to invertible $2\times2$ matrices, or equivalently ordered bases of ${\bf F}_p^2$: there are $\square$ many vectors to choose from for the first vector in a basis, and $\square$ many vectors to choose from for the second vector, so there are $\square$-many bases total.

Now consider the kernel of $\det:{\rm GL}_2({\bf F}_p)\to{\bf F}_p^\times$ in light of the $1$st isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way.
Take $GL(2,Z_p)$
and consider the matrix row vectors as $r_1,r_2$.
Clearly $r_1$ has $p^2$ choices(why?).
But as we want $\det \ne 0$ $r_1$ has $p^2-1$ choices.
Now $r_2$ has $p^2-p$ choices(as the rows must be linearly independent so $r_2 \ne cr_1$ for some $c \in Z_p$).
So $\vert GL_2(Z_p) \rvert = (p^2-1)(p^2-p)$
Now consider the homomorphism $f : GL \rightarrow Z_p$ 
given by $f(A)=\det(A)$.

So, by 1st iso theorem, $\lvert SL_2(Z_p) \rvert=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)/(p-1)$.

Comment: Without mathJax, your answer is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

> If $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ denotes finite field of order q then order of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{F}_{q})$is $\frac{1}{q-1}\prod_{{i=0}}^{{n -1}}(q^{n}-q^{i})$

Comment: Then option 1 is the right choice.Is not it?

Comment: Yes, it is. $\phantom{ }$