# Finding $|Aut(\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15})|$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, chinese-remainder-theorem, general-linear-group

I am trying to compute:

$|Aut(\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15})|$

I know that:

1. If $H$ and $K$ have coprime orders then:

   $Aut(K \times H) \cong Aut(K)\times Aut(H) $
2. For prime $p$:

   $ GL(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) = Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) $

I thought of doing something like:

$|Aut(\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15})|=|Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{5}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3})|=|Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2^2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3^2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}^2)|$

(but why can I swap the order in the last transition?) **(Q1)**

and then:

$=|Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2^2)|\cdot |Aut(\mathbb{Z}_3^2)| \cdot |Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{5}^2)| $

(but why does this hold? Fact no. 1 is only for two groups and of coprime order...) **(Q2)**

and from here I want to use fact no. 2 somehow, but I'm not sure how to compute $ |GL(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)| $ **(Q3)**

Any assistance with my questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Q3: see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259973/how-to-find-gl-2f-p) for example. Q1: $G\times H\cong H\times G$. Q2: Indeed, $2,3,5$ are coprime.

Comment: For $Q_1$ you can! You're applying the map $(a,b) \to (b,a)$ many times from a direct product to a direct product. I should add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- By the Chinese remainder theorem:
  $$\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}\\\cong (\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \times (\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \times (\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5)\\ \cong (\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \times (\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \times (\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5)$$
  On **(Q1)**: We used the pretty obvious commutativity law $G \times H \cong H\times G$ in this step. To work out the details, show that $\phi : G\times H \to H\times G, (g,h) \mapsto (h,g)$ is an isomorphism of groups. Also, we used associativity of $\times$ (up to isomorphism), which is $(G \times H) \times K \cong G\times (H\times K)$, which has a similarly trivial proof.
- As you said, you can split Aut over groups of coprime order, so:
  $$\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}) \\ 
  \cong \operatorname{Aut}((\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \times (\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \times (\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5)) \\
  \cong \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \times \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \times \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \\ \cong \operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \times \operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \times \operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \\ = \operatorname{GL}(2,2) \times \operatorname{GL}(2,3) \times \operatorname{GL}(2,5)$$
  Note that the splitting has been done alredy in this step, answering **(Q2)**.
- **(Q3)** There is the formula $\#\operatorname{GL}(n,q) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(q^n - q^i)$ from linear algebra (counting the number of ordered bases of the $\mathbb{F}_q$ vector space $\mathbb{F}_q^n$), therefore
  $$\#\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}) \\ = 
  \#(\operatorname{GL}(2,2) \times \operatorname{GL}(2,3) \times \operatorname{GL}(2,5)) \\ =
  \#\operatorname{GL}(2,2) \cdot \#\operatorname{GL}(2,3) \cdot \#\operatorname{GL}(2,5) \\ = 6 \cdot 48 \cdot 480 \\ = 138240.$$

Comment: Have to say -- thanks for the great answer! The way you've written it really highlighted my own thinking flaws... especially in your second point (I mistakenly continued to think of the groups as $\mathbb{Z}_6, \mathbb{Z}_{10}...$ which are not coprime). Very helpful - thanks!

Comment: @Anon thank you for your feedback...